# What is the little white gap for my CSS?

Tags: html, css

There is a little white gap on the downside of `mainBox`, what is it and which cause it?

```css
body {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid black;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#wrapper {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
#container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background: black;
}
#mainBox {
  width: 75%;
  height: 150px;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}
#sideBox {
  width: 25%;
  height: 100px;
  background: yellow;
  float: left;
}
#footer {
  clear: both;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="header">this is the header
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="mainBox">main box
    </div>
    <div id="sideBox">side box
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="footer">this is the footer
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `border: none` to `#container`

```css
body{
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;}
div{
    border:1px solid black;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size:30px;}
#wrapper{
    width:900px;
    margin:0px auto;}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;}
#container{
    border: none;      /**** Add this extra line ****/
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:black;}
#mainBox{
    width:75%;
    height:150px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    }
#sideBox{
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
    }
#footer{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:white;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">this is the header
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="mainBox">main box
        </div>
        <div id="sideBox">side box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">this is the footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `#sideBox` have `100px`  height and `#mainBox` have `150px` height. Make both same solve your issue.

Here i set `#sideBox` to `height:150px;`

And you have given parent container `#container` to `height:100px` and child to `height:150px`.

**Edit:**

I think i misunderstood your issue before. But as i say above. Your parent height is small then your child. Make it proper solve your issue.

```css
body{
      margin:0px;
      padding:0px;}
div{
    border:1px solid black;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    font-size:30px;}
#wrapper{
    width:900px;
    margin:0px auto;}
#header{
    width:100%;
    height:100px;
    background:red;}
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:150px;
    background:black;}
#mainBox{
    width:75%;
    height:150px;
    background:blue;
    float:left;
    }
#sideBox{
    width:25%;
    height:100px;
    background:yellow;
    float:left;
    }
#footer{
    clear:both;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
    background:white;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">this is the header
    </div>
    <div id="container">
        <div id="mainBox">main box
        </div>
        <div id="sideBox">side box
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="footer">this is the footer
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a white gap here because your blue div (#mainBox) is 150px, which is taller than its container div (#container), set at 100px. This has caused the #mainBox div to extend outside the container with a slight offset at the leftmost side due to the black border applied to the div.

There are a number of ways to correct this gap, such as removing the border or the hardcoded height values.